# MacBook Pro suddenly started to freeze with any action (using SSD)

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I'm having a trouble with my MacBook Pro (Mid 2012).

I have upgraded it (5 months ago) to use a Kingston SSD instead of a SATA, and everything was perfect. Very fast and smooth...until yesterday. I was working and then when it was time to go home, i just pull down the monitor and the macbook went to sleep. When i came home and open my MacBook, it was just a disaster, EVERY SINGLE action, even click on any button, causes to freeze and the apple colorful ball (loading) appears.

Today i tried to put another SSD (samsung) to test if was my SSD that has a problem, but the problem remained. Then i tried to use a simple SATA and everything is normal (i'm asking now from my macbook with a SATA HD).

What do you think it could be?

This are my configs:
 - **MacBook Pro Mid 2012**
 - **13"**
 - **i7**
 - **12Gb RAM**
 - **Intel graphics 1024**
 - **El Capitain OS X**

p.s.: My SSD is almost full.

Comment: Did you happen to recently install the 10.11.2 update for El Capitan?

Comment: I really dont know if i have updated El Capitan. But lets assume that i have updated. The problem occurs when i use the SSD in my MacBook, i have tested in my friends MacBook (that is late 2012) and works like a charm.

Comment: @WitaloBenicio It has been sometime. But I was wondering whether you found some solution to this. As I have exactly same problem.

Comment: @IJR yes, i figured out what as going on. It was a problem with the flex cable of HD

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a faulty SATA cable. Others have reported this same problem when upgrading from a standard HD to a SSD with Mid-2012 MacBook Pro laptops.

You can find more information over at Apple’s Support site:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/24783957#24783957

Comment: I read the discussion and the problem there is that the cable was not recognizing the SSD as a bootable drive. Mine is recognized but after 5 months, it started to freeze when doing any action.